# JPQL left join with clause where

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this two entities with manyToOne relationship,
this is my Transfer entity :

```
@Entity
public class Transfer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer id;
private String status;
private Task task;

public Transfer() {
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
@ManyToOne
public Task getTask() {
    return task;
}
public void setTask(Task task) {
    this.task = task;
}
}
```

and this is the Taks Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private String code;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public Boolean getIsLast() {
    return isLast;
}

public void setIsLast(Boolean isLast) {
    this.isLast = isLast;
}

}
```

now I want to get the tasks whose his transfers children have a status equal to somevalue, how can I resolve it with JPQL ?

this what I get when I try to list the categories (one-to-many side ):
[image]

Comment: "select distinct task from Transfer transfer join transfer.task task where transfer.status = somevalue"

Comment: thanks so lot @Chris , so I must have a bi-directional one-to-many many-to-one between the two entities , but when I implement the bidriectional relationship , I will get an error in the JSON response when I get all the tasks, how can I resolve that ?

Comment: You don't need a bidirectional oneToMany with the query above, and unless you need it in your object model, I wouldn't add it.  As for serializing to/from JSON, I would form a new complete question to outline the problem